# Months array throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException java

Tags: java, android, calendar, indexoutofboundsexception

In my Hijri calendar app, if I click on the next month button and reach till the end of year (i.e. the last month) or if I click on the prev Month button till I reach the beginning of the year (i.e. the first month), the app crashes and throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
    private ImageView calendarToJournalButton;
    private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
    private final String[] hmonths = {"Muharram", "Safar", "Rabi al-Awwal", "Rabi al-Akhir", "Jamadi al-Awwal", "Jamadi al-Akhir", "Rajab", "Shabaan", "Ramadhan", "Shawwal", "Zilqad", "Zilhajj"};
    private Button currentMonth;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    private int month, year, hmonth, hyear;
    private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";
    private String hmonthname;
    private HijriCalendar hijri;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.simple_calendar_view);

            _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            hijri = new HijriCalendar(_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            hmonth = hijri.getHijriMonth();
            hmonthname = hijri.getHijriMonthName();
            hyear = hijri.getHijriYear();

            Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: " + year);
            Log.d(tag, "Islamic Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + hmonth + " " + "Year: " + hyear);

            selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
            selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

            prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
            prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

            currentMonth = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
            currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime()) + " | " + hmonthname + " " + hyear);

            nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
            nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

            calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

            // Initialised
            adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, hmonth, hyear);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


    /**
     * 
     * @param month
     * @param year
     */
    private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year, int hmonth, int hyear)
        {
            adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, hmonth, hyear);
            _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            currentMonth.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime())  + " | " + getHMonthAsString(hmonth) + " " + hyear);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    //Hijri Month
    private String getHMonthAsString(int i)
        {
            return hmonths[i];
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (v == prevMonth)
                {
                    if (month <= 1)
                        {
                            month = 12;
                            year--;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            month--;
                        }
                    if (hmonth <= 1)
                    {
                        hmonth = 12;
                        hyear--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hmonth--;
                    }
                    Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: " + month + " Year: " + year);
                    Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Islamic Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: " + hmonth + " Year: " + hyear);
                    setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year, hmonth, hyear);
                }
            if (v == nextMonth)
                {
                    if (month > 11)
                        {
                            month = 1;
                            year++;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            month++;
                        }
                    if (hmonth > 11)
                    {

                        hmonth = 1;
                        hyear++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hmonth++;
                    }
                    Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: " + month + " Year: " + year);
                    Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Islamic Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: " + hmonth + " Year: " + hyear);
                    setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year, hmonth, hyear);

                }

        }
```

The logcat shows the error at this line:

```
currentMonth.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime())  + " | " + getHMonthAsString(hmonth) + " " + hyear);
```

at `getHMonthAsString(hmonth)` in `setGridCellAdapterToDate` method.

If I replace `getHMonthAsString(hmonth)` with `hmonth`, the calendar loops the years and months correctly and works fine without any errors, but then it does not display the month names, just the numbers.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are 0-based. If month is 12, as you set in `onClick`, you're past the end of your array.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == prevMonth) {
        if (month <= 1) {
            month = 12; // Ouch.
```

---

Also, while I realizing source formatting is largely a matter of religion, particularly when posting IMO it's best to reduce vertical and horizontal whitespace. Two levels of indentation for a single block seems excessive. Code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is ;)

---

Editors: be mindful of the information you're adding and removing.

Comment: Got the code from here: http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/  This works for the Gregorian calendar. It's the Hijri calendar I'm having trouble with. If I replace `getHMonthAsString(hmonth)` with `hmonth`, the Hijri calendar works as well, but does not show the month names, only numbers.

Comment: "Code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is ;)" <- It's a graph representing which sections likely have the greatest need for change.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about formatting. Will keep in mind. :)

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand the problem.

Comment: Actually I was adding info like 0 to 12 and in that time you and other user have added and removed info so it become messy, I just tried to put more info while there was only one line.

Comment: Not trying to prove anything as your repo says/proves much more, I thought you were in hurry and wont return so added that,please dont mind..as seems like you mind that and put that line in answer.

Comment: @MKJParekh, DaveNewton: I rolled back because I thought that the comment on source formatting was a good bit of advice and didn't think it needed to be removed. Then I added back what MKJParekh put after he removed the source formatting comment because that seemed to be useful as well.